# If $p_1 < p_2 < \cdots<p_M $ for some PMF $(p_j)$ then $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{M}(j-1)p_j \geq \frac{(M-1)}{2}$

Tags: probability, lagrange-multiplier

> For any positive integer $M$ and probabilities $p_j$ for $j=1,2,...,M$, which are arranged in ascending order, i.e.
>   $p_1 < p_2 < ...<p_M $, 
>   one has $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{M}(j-1)p_j \geq \frac{M-1}{2}$.

For uniform distribution i.e. $p_1=p_2=\ldots=p_M=1/M$, the equality holds

$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{M}(j-1)p_j= \frac{1}{M}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{M}(j-1)= \frac{1}{M}\frac{(M-1)M}{2}= \frac{(M-1)}{2}$.

But, how to prove for any probability distribution?

My intuition is, by using Lagrange Multipliers, we can prove that minimum value occurs for uniform distribution.

Comment: For what it's worth, we have
$$\sum_{j=1}^{M}{(j-1){p_j}} = \sum_{j=1}^{M}{j{p_j}} - \sum_{j=1}^{M}{p_j} = E[J] - 1,$$
where $J$ is the random variable representing the $j$'s, with probability mass function given by $p_j$ for $j = 1, 2, \ldots, M$.

Comment: Hint: Expand the LHS of the inequality $$\sum_{j=1}^M\sum_{k=1}^M\left((j-1)-(k-1)\right)\cdot(p_j-p_k)\geqslant0.$$ No Lagrange multiplier involved, only algebra and the identity $2\sum\limits_{j=1}^M(j-1)=M(M-1)$ .

Comment: Did: How did you come up with the expression? It should be as below: $\sum_{j=1}^{M}(j-1)p_j \geq \frac{M-1}{2}$ and same way $\sum_{k=1}^{M}(k-1)p_k \geq \frac{M-1}{2}$. Subtracting both, we get $\sum_{j=1}^{M}(j-1)p_j - \sum_{k=1}^{M}(k-1)p_k $. Now, $\sum_{j=1}^{M}(j-1)p_j * \sum_{k=1}^{M}p_k - \sum_{j=1}^{M} p_j * \sum_{k=1}^{M}(k-1)p_k$. Therefore, we can write, $\sum_{j=1}^{M} \sum_{k=1}^{M}(j-1)p_j p_k - \sum_{j=1}^{M} \sum_{k=1}^{M}(k-1)p_j p_k$. Therefore, $\sum_{j=1}^{M} \sum_{k=1}^{M}[(j-1)-(k-1)]p_j p_k$

Comment: Arnie: How to prove $E(J)-1 \geq \frac{M-1}{2}$. However, we need to prove that minimum expected value of $E(J)$ occurs only for uniform distribution and for any other distribution $E(J)\geq\frac{(M+1)}{2}$,